# configurar inputs e label com css

Tags: html, css

Estou com dificuldade para alinhar o label com o input radio, a label fica embaixo e o input em cima. estou utilizando html e css. queria que os dois ficassem na mesma linha com o input radio atrás da label.

código:

```
<h2>Em outros jogos, qual seu estilo de personagem/jogada favorito?</h2>
       <input type="radio" name="selectxt" id="selectn4">
       <label for="selectn4">Muito dano, porém lento, e resistente</label>
```

css:

```
input[type = radio]{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

}

bom, talvez só tenha que chamar o label de alguma forma, porém não tenho esse conhecimento.

Comment: Se colocar o input após o label e sem css fica como?

Comment: Pq vc está colocando display:flex no Radio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta Remover as propriedades css e ficara da forma que você deseja

```html
    <div>   
    <h2>Em outros jogos, qual seu estilo de personagem/jogada favorito?</h2>
        <input type="radio" name="selectxt" id="selectn4">
        <label for="selectn4">Muito dano, porém lento, e resistente</label>
</div>
```